# Numpy multidimensional advanced indexing

Tags: numpy

I have an array `a` with shape `[3,x,y,z,n]` (three 4d-images). And a second array `b` with shape `[x,y,z]` which contains the indices I want to choose from the first dimension of `a` (so the values of `b` are in the range 0 to 2).
The results I want to have would be of shape `[x,y,z,n]`. How can I do that in numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
a[b,np.arange(x)[:,None,None],np.arange(y)[:,None],np.arange(z)]
```

A shorter way to express that would be -

```
a[tuple([b] + np.ogrid[:x,:y,:z])]
```

Using NumPy builtin [`np.take_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) to perform advanced-indexing by doing the dirty work under the hoods -

```
np.take_along_axis(a,b[None,...,None],axis=0)[0]
```